# iPhone Configuration Utlity - Disabling Camera App Also Disables UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I searched so hard but couldn't find a proper way to overcome this problem.
I am building an app for iPad2. Our company will give iPad2's to sales staff but they will disable the Camera App using Configuration Utility.

My app uses UIImagePicker and gives ability to user take some photos about the project.
But disabling Camera also disables the UIImagePicker controller.

Can I only disable the iPad camera app not the camera API?

(Note: I will not submit this app to AppStore, It will be used in organization only.So I can use any dirty way that Apple doesn't love. But I cannot jailbreak it.)

Edit:
May I use private api's in order to use camera OR May I use private api's in order to disable only camera app.(like deleting camera app),I know it's sandboxed but I am trying to find a solution without jailbreaking it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm 99% sure you can't do that because UIImagePicker uses the Camera API. And when you disable the Camera you are disabling ANY Camera app the user might install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, time passed away.. iOS6 is on the market now. As my research, still lacks specific app locking.
But there is a new option named "Lock to App" that converts iOS device to a kiosk like, one app running machine.

We are considering to use that feature.